# How to create a dynamic date title in excel 2010 using different tables and data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

My friend has asked for help with an excel assignment and they have 2 tables, HRM and Data_Tables.

Data_Tables has corresponding month numbers from 1-12 in column I from I3-I14. In J column there is the month name which is from January-December in J3-J14. In L column there is day numbers from 1-7 in L3-L9. In M column there is day names from Sunday - Saturday from M3-M9.

Here is a picture [image: a picture].

The question is to derive a formula (in a merged cell from A2-I2 in the HRM table) that uses the base of 'HRM: DayName the DayDate of Month, Year' where DayName pulls from the table Data_Tables and changes DayName, DayDate, month and year, also adding 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'ft' with an IF statement to the end of DayDate. So this means if the document is opened on the Friday the 15th of January, 2026, the title will be "HRM: Friday the 15th of January, 2026".

Comment: please add same example of current data and desired output, your question is too concentrated now.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I'm also not confident with adding tables, easiest if you just add a screenshot.

Comment: oh ok i will add it

Comment: i cant add a picture so i will give you a link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfl8hq7u8d12cbj/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need the helper sheet to achieve this, try this formula: `="HRM: "&text(today(),"dddd")&" the "&text(today(),"d")&MID("thstndrdth",MIN(9,2*MOD(day(TODAY()),10)*(MOD(day(TODAY())-11,100)>2)+1),2)&" of "&text(today(),"mmmm")&" "&year(today())`

Comment: I'm happy if works. If you're confident with it, please mark my answer as a solution.